# Extracting metadata from csv without loading data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to get the dimensions (shape) of a data frame using pandas in python without reading the entire data frame first in memory given that the file is quite large.

To get the number of columns with minimal loading of the file into the memory, I can for example use the argument below.

```py
import pandas as pd
pd = pd.read_csv("myData.csv", nrows=1)
print(pd.shape)
```

To get the row numbers I can use the argument `usecols = [1]` when reading the file but there must be a simpler way of doing this.

If there are other packages or scripts that can easily give me such metadata information, I would be happy as well. It is really metadata I am looking for such as column names, number of rows, number of columns etc but I don't want to read the entire file in!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need pandas for this. Use the built-in `csv` module to parse the file:

```
import csv

with open('myData.csv')as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    headers = next(reader)        # The header row is now consumed
    ncol = len(headers)
    nrow = sum(1 for _ in reader) # What remains are the data rows
```

Comment: So my understanding is that the above script is a context manager which iterates over the csv, instead of reading the csv in memory in full, which is why you used the `next(reader)` argument to get the `ncol` for example?

Comment: Also, is there a way to get the column names?

Comment: It uses context manager, but is not a context manager in itself. It uses context manager to open the file. `reader` is an *iterator*. To consume an interator, you can call `next`, use list comprehension or loop over it. On each iteration, it gives you a new row in the CSV file.